# Shared ViewModel across two/or more fragments and an activity using Dagger

Tags: android, dagger-2

Well, as I tried to summarise in the title, here is the details.

We have a relatively large application, that uses Dagger, in really not ideal ways, so we decided to start writing tests, and for that, I needed to expose dependencies for Mockito, hence, I faced an issue to start provide view models using a singleton factory, still applicable and there is tons of tutorials around that explains this.

We have across our app, a lot of features, that is implemented using a single activity, and a navigation component, that single activity sometimes have a created view model that we use to share data between the container activity and the fragments populated using the navigation editor.

What I couldn't figure out is the following, how can I use dagger to inject a shared view model, to return the same instance each time I invoke `@Inject` for a specific view model, I know it could be done through scopes maybe, but I couldn't figure it out, and I have an explanation that I need to be verified. (I will provide my code below)

I started by implementing my Singleton ViewModelFactory as follows:

```
@Singleton
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>,
        @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val creator = creators[modelClass] ?: creators.entries.firstOrNull {
            modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key)
        }?.value ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")
        try {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created my ViewModelModule that provides the ViewModelFactory and the ViewModel as follows:

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelFactoryModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindsViewModelFactory(viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @EbMainScope
    @ViewModelKey(EBMainContainerViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindEbMainViewModel(ebMainContainerViewModel: EBMainContainerViewModel): ViewModel

}
```

And before you ask, here is the scope implementation:

```
@Scope
@Target(
        AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION,
        AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER,
        AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER
)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class EbMainScope
```

Last step, here is my activity/fragment injectors module:

```
@Module
abstract class ScreensBuildersModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    @EbMainScope
    abstract fun contributeEbMainActivity(): EBMainActivity

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    @EbMainScope
    abstract fun contributeEbDashboardMainFragment(): EBDashboardMainFragment

}
```

Of course I wired everything in the AppComponent, and the app ran smoothly, with the catch, that there was two instances of `EbMainContainerViewModel`, despite me defining the scope.

My explanation was, I actually had two different providers rather than one, but I still cannot understand why, since I marked it as `@Singleton`.

Does someone has an explanation to this ? If more input is needed let me know guys.

Comment: I was facing a similar problem the other day, I believe, and I think the only required change was using the `@Reusable` annotation in place of `@Singleton`. The details of why this fixed things is lost on me and I don't have time to figure this out ATM. I used `@Reusable` on both the ViewModelFactory and the ViewModel class itself and that seemed to sort out duplicates for me.

Comment: Thanks mate for your answer, I actually ended up instead of doing this using scopes, delegated this to the android framework itself, used the `activity?.run` to initiate a shared view model on the main thread, from the activity / fragment, the fragment would end up creating the same instance of viewmodel because it is already created on the `activity`, hence that activity object is the already holder Activity for the fragment, problem solved.

Comment: @OmarK.Rostom I am having the same issue. Could you share your exact solution?

Comment: @orbitbot please share your solution

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, but fix it this way:

1. I use for example this code:
   https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/tree/dagger-android
2. In my fragments (in which I wanted to use Shared ViewModel) I use
   this (it helped me):

   ```
   private val viewModel by viewModels<SearchViewModel>({ activity as MainActivity }) { viewModelFactory }
   ```

   instead of this(as in sample):

   ```
   private val viewModel by viewModels<SearchViewModel> { viewModelFactory }
   ```

Because the first argument is **ownerProducer**, so we create a ViewModel in the activity scope.

Answer (score 0):

Okay then, here is practical guide I have managed to do, a solution I guess viable, and since @pratz9999 asked for a solution, here it is:

In order to instantiate a ViewModel, you would need a ViewModelProvider, which under the hood creates a ViewModelFactory, if you would depend on the above implementation, for each entry in the module (i.e @IntoMap call) a new provider will be instantiated (which is fines) but here goes the catch, it will create a new ViewModelFactory each time, take a look at the following:

```
/**
* Creates a {@link ViewModelProvider}, which retains ViewModels while a scope of given
* {@code fragment} is alive. More detailed explanation is in {@link ViewModel}.
* <p>
* It uses the given {@link Factory} to instantiate new ViewModels.
*
* @param fragment a fragment, in whose scope ViewModels should be retained
* @param factory  a {@code Factory} to instantiate new ViewModels
* @return a ViewModelProvider instance
*/
@NonNull
@MainThread
public static ViewModelProvider of(@NonNull Fragment fragment, @Nullable Factory factory) {
    Application application = checkApplication(checkActivity(fragment));
    if (factory == null) {
        factory = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application);
    }
    return new ViewModelProvider(fragment.getViewModelStore(), factory);
}
```

My fault as I guessed after some research, that I did not inject the proper ViewModelFactory, so I ended up doing the following:

- In my base fragment class, I injected a ViewModelFactory as follows:

```
/**
* Factory for injecting view models
*/
@Inject
lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
```

- Then in a utility class, I had a method that returns a shared ViewModel as follows (Note the activity?.run this makes the view model instance binded to the holding activity, and thus having the shared scope concept):

```
fun <T: ViewModel> BaseNavFragmentWithDagger.getSharedViewModelWithParams(clazz: Class<T>): T =
        activity?.run { ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(clazz) }
                ?: throw RuntimeException("You called the view model too early")
```

- And finally for private ViewModels I went with this:

```
fun <T: ViewModel> BaseNavFragmentWithDagger.getPrivateViewModelWithParams(clazz: Class<T>): T =
        ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(clazz)
```

Comment: Hope this helps @pratz9999.